# How to align a GtkWidget label in the center of its GtkWidget layout in C with GTK3?

Tags: c, widget, label, alignment, gtk3

I have the following code, and I'm struggling to align the label in the center
of its parent (layout), but nothing has worked for me:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *layout;
    GtkWidget *label;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 1024, 600);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

    layout = gtk_layout_new(NULL, NULL);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), layout);

    label = gtk_label_new(NULL);
    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(label), "SOME TEXT");
    gtk_layout_put(GTK_LAYOUT(layout), label, 0, 0);

    // Here I'm trying to align my label to the center,
    // but it doesn't work with any of the three functions
    gtk_widget_set_halign(label, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
    //gtk_label_set_xalign(GTK_LABEL(label), GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
    //gtk_misc_set_alignment(GTK_MISC(label), 0.5f, 0.5f);




    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

I have also tryied some other functions that I could find in the GENOME documentation and other SO questions but they are mostly deprecated, or also doesn't work. At this point, as I'm working with GTK3, the recommended way seems to be with:

> gtk_widget_set_halign(label, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);

But it is not working. The label is still at the position I put it with:

> gtk_layout_put(GTK_LAYOUT(layout), label, 512, 300);

The code compiles without any errors or warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GtkLayout`, like its relative `GtkFixed`, is kind of a last-resort container that you use when none of the other containers will work for your purpose. It just puts widgets where you specify them. So, the horizontal alignment APIs will not work. With `GtkLayout`, you have to calculate the alignment yourself.

I would recommend using `GtkGrid` or one of the other, more full-featured containers.

Comment: You are right, I already ended up using `GtkGrid` ... still mixed with the `GtkLayout` at the moment, but at least it is working. However, I will check your answer as correct because it is, and it just helps me confirm that I'm on the right way. Thanks :)

Comment: Draw attention to one big difference. GtkLayout can shrink, but GtkGrid, GtkFixed cannot. This hinders windows from shrinking, in case contained widgets cannot be shrinked (ex. GtkLabel, GtkImage etc.). So if you depend on it (ex. if you calculate the new allocated size in order to "resize" contained widgets) then you should use GtkLayout.

Also GtkLayout may be smaller than your widget. In that case centering will set some of contained widget outside GtkLayout (a.k.a partially hidden).